# Inserting record in zoho api v2 in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, zoho

I want to insert data in zoho crm using api v2. first make an array then i encoded json .Request url **https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Contacts**. 
But i got this error.

**Code:**

```
$authtoken = ***********;
$fields={"data":["{\"Last_Name\":\"Test John insert\",\"Email\":\"testjhon@jhon.com\"}"]};

$zoho_url = "https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Contacts";
```

**Error:**

```
{"data":[{"code":"INVALID_DATA","details":{"expected_data_type":"jsonobject","index":0},"message":"invalid data","status":"error"}]}
```

Comment: maybe you need to explicitly set your content type as application json or something along with your cURL request

Comment: it's an issue , but doesn't work. Thank's @Ghost

Answer (score 2):

Working example:

```
$fields = json_encode(
    array(
        "data" => array([
            "Company"   => "abc",
            "Last_Name" => "Tom",
            "City"      => "Egham" 
        ],
        [   
            "Company"   => "abc",
            "Last_Name" => "Jerry",
            "City"      => "Egham"
        ])
    )
);
```

Send headers this way :

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields),
    sprintf('Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken %s', $oauth)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this json array:

```
$fields = "{\"data\":[{\"Last_Name\": \"Test\",\"First_Name\": \"TESTING\",\"Email\": \"demo@w3scloud.com\"}],\"trigger\":[\"approval\",\"workflow\"]}";
```

Answer (score 1):

send this way :

```
[{ "data": \[ { "Company":"company name", "Last_Name":"your last name", "Phone":"123456789", "First_Name": "your first name", "Email":"first@gmail.com" } \], “triggger”:\[“workflow”,”approval”,”blueprint”\] }]
```

[click here to view image (request and response via postman)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol3yG.png)

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that Zoho seems to want an extra pair of brackets around the data. And you might try encoding the data array to a JSON-string *before* sending it to cURL.

```
$fields = json_encode([
    ["data" => ["Last_Name" => "Test John insert","Email" => "testjhon@jhon.com"]],
]);
```

As @Ghost mentioned, you may also need to change the content-type. According to the [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-notes), passing an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` will set the content-type to `multipart/form-data`; what you probably want is `application/json`.

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: ".$authtoken,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send the json file to zoho api, and all be works.:

```
  $fields=["data"=> ['Last_Name'=>'Test John insert','Email'=>'testjhon@jhon.com']];
  $fields = json_encode($fields);
```

Comment: That's more or less the same as rideron89's answer, except they say you need an extra array wrapping that object?